# What makes an electric fence non lethal?

Tags: current

I guess the simple answer is the low current, but how is that achieved considering the high voltage?

Answer (score 5):

What is dangerous for the human (or animal) body is the current (and the duration of the current). The image below shows what the effects of current are depending on duration (source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury))

[image: effects of current vs duration]

If we consider the human body as a resistor R (500 to 100 000 ohms depending conditions, current, person, wet or not, etc.,) then with an ideal voltage source (ie one with low internal resistance), the current is proportional to the voltage U: I=U/R. Most "normal" power sources (electric network at home, bateries, etc.)  aim to have a low internal resistance r (that is, being nearly an ideal current source.) For such sources, current is (nearly) proportionnal to voltage, so people tend to simplify and say "high voltage is dangerous," instead of saying that the current is dangerous.

A fence, however, has a very high internal resistance (r is much biger than R) so we now have this internal resistance in series with the body.  The current is no longer I=U/R, but I=U/(r+R), which is far smaller.

So basically, a fence is not dangerous because the internal resistance is high enough to limit the current.

If we look at it another way, there is a voltage divider between the body resistor R and the internal resistor r,  so the body only sees a voltage Ubody=U*R/(R+r). If the internal resistance r is big enough, the body "sees" only a very small current.

In adition to using a high internal resistance to limit current, fences usually only send short current pulses instead of continuous current. That reduces the danger (and the power consumption.)

Finally, why use high voltages at all? Simply because there are often "insulators" (your shoes, hooves for the horses, etc.) between the body and the ground (which is the return path.) Most insulators start conducting when a high enough voltage is applied

Answer (score 4):

An electric fence is typically driven by discharging a capacitor of known voltage through a step up transformer to produce a high voltage spike. The charged capacitor has a known limited energy content which means the high voltage output will also have a limited energy content. An AED will discharge from 50 to 300 joules to defibrillate a heart, an electric fence will deliver around 5 to 500 milijoules.

Answer (score 3):

> *how is that achieved considering the high voltage?*

High voltage in series with an internal high impedance means the voltage can penetrate the quite thick and mainly dry skin of an animal but, only with a small (non lethal) current.

It's Ohm's law in action.

Comment: Ohm's law in action; when a mate relieves himself on a fence you warned him about :)

Comment: You never know you like something until you try it @SolarMike

Comment: I don't get it, it's supposed to be non lethal for humans too, and they can get killed with 1/30 of that voltage.

Comment: ["Volts jolt but mils kill"](https://tynaghnetworks.ie/cms/transformer-let-through-voltages/) as the old saying goes. Translation, it's current that kills; it stops the heart and fries the brain (or whatever). Think of voltage as the delivery mechanism. If you produce 10,000 volts and there's 10 Mohm in series with it, you can deliver 1 mA of current into a short circuit and, if the loading impedance is (say) 1000 kohm, the voltage developed is 909 volts but, the current is still largely 1 mA (0.91 mA) @ESB691 - just do the Ohm's law stuff.

Comment: Ok, but where does that high impedance you talking about comes from?

Comment: @ESB691 A resistor, active current-limiting circuit, or other high impedance circuit.

Comment: @SolarMike I think the mythbusters did that once (somehow... dunno how they got the tv channel to let them!) and concluded that it wouldn't actually cause a problem (for humans, anyway) but is still a monumentally foolish thing to do.

Comment: @ESB91 think about static electricity as a comparison. Hundreds of thousands of volts can be generated walking across a carpet and, we get a jolt touching water taps and door handles etc. but, the current is very limited and it doesn't harm a normal person. The electric fence controller is purposely designed to limit it's output current and has components that do that.